# glTexCoordPointer output not as expected

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer-objects, texture1d

I am trying to use `glDrawElements` , `glTexCoordPointer` and `glTexImage1D` to create a 1D texture, render a surface dataset and color the vertices according to their height value.

```
GLuint tex = 0;
```

My texture generation:

```
glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex );
unsigned char pixels[] =
{
    255, 0, 0, 255,
    0, 255, 0, 255,
    0, 0, 255, 255,
};
glTexImage1D( GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA, 3, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );
glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
```

`vArray` is an array which stores the vertices for rendering.

```
float vArray[12] = {  
   0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
   0.0, 3.0, 1.0,
   1.0, 2.0, 0.0,
   1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
}
```

`iArray` is an array which stores the indices for rendering.

```
int iSize = 6;
int iArray[6] = {  
   0, 2, 1,
   2, 1, 4,
}
```

`tArray` is an array which stores the normalised heights.

```
GLfloat tArray[4] = {  
   0.0, 0.3, 1.0, 0.0,
}
```

My render code:

```
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
  glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex);
  glTexCoordPointer(1, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GL_FLOAT), tArray);

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glVertexPointer(3 ,GL_FLOAT,0, vArray);    

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, iSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, iArray);

  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_1D);
```

The final output is not as I expected, hoping somebody can point out my mistakes.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I do have this enabled in my code, forgot to add to question. Its added now.

Comment: You show the definition of `vArray` twice but never the one of `tArray`. You should also clearify what `is not as I expected` means for the output. Nothing draw? Other colors than expected? Other location than expected? What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- RE: your `glTexCoordPointer()` call: Tightly-packed arrays usually use `0` for `stride`.
- `vArray` and `tArray` only have four elements, not five, so the `4` in `iArray` will cause OpenGL to read off the ends of those arrays into garbage (if you're lucky) or segfaults (if you're not).

All together:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint tex = 0;
void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    float vArray[] =
    {
       -0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, -0.5,
        0.5,  0.5,
       -0.5,  0.5,
    };

    GLfloat tArray[] =
    {
       0.0, 0.3, 1.0, 0.0,
    };

    unsigned int iArray[] =
    {
       0, 1, 2,
       2, 3, 0,
    };

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_1D );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex );
    glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
    glTexCoordPointer( 1, GL_FLOAT, 0, tArray );

    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vArray );

    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, iArray );

    glDisableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_1D );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 400, 400 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glewInit();

    glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_1D, tex );
    unsigned char pixels[] =
    {
        255, 0, 0, 255,
        0, 255, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 255, 255,
    };
    glTexImage1D( GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGBA, 3, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );
    glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: 2D version:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint tex = 0;
void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    float vArray[] =
    {
       -0.5, -0.5,
        0.5, -0.5,
        0.5,  0.5,
       -0.5,  0.5,
    };

    GLfloat tArray[] =
    {
       0.0, 0.0,
       1.0, 0.0,
       1.0, 1.0,
       0.0, 1.0,
    };

    unsigned int iArray[] =
    {
       0, 1, 2,
       2, 3, 0,
    };

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
    glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
    glTexCoordPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tArray );

    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vArray );

    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, iArray );

    glDisableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 400, 400 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glewInit();

    glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
    unsigned char pixels[] =
    {
        255, 0, 0, 255,
        0, 255, 0, 255,
        0, 0, 255, 255,
        0, 0, 255, 255,
    };
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );
    glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this was a 2D texture, where the horizontal gradient went form red to green, and the vertical gradient got more blue, how would the pixels and the tArray array change?

Comment: @tester: Edited in a 2D version; mostly just `GL_TEXTURE_1D` -> `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, some extra texture pixels, and 2D texture coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I understand what I was doing wrong now.